# Doctrine2 Symfony2 innerJoin QueryException Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'

Tags: php, mysql, exception, symfony, doctrine-orm

As part of my website I'm trying to a create tagging (folksonomy) system using Symfony2 and Doctrine2.

I'm following the table and query examples in the document below to create my Doctrine Entities: http://dablog.ulcc.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tagging_folksonomy.pdf

When I try to convert the MySQL queries (given in the document) to Doctrine Query Builder queries I get errors with the innerJoins.  Example below:

MySQL query from the document:

```
SELECT tag_text
, COUNT(*) as num_tags
FROM Tag2Post t2p
INNER JOIN Tags t
ON t2p.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY tag_text;
```

My Doctrine Query Builder query:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
          ->select('t.tag_text, COUNT(*) as num_tags')
          ->from('CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tag2Post', 't2p')
          ->innerJoin('CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tags', 't', 'ON', 't2p.tag_id = t.id')
          ->groupBy('t.tag_text')
;
$tags = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Error message:

```
[2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 112: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT t.tag_text, COUNT(*) as num_tags FROM CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tag2Post t2p INNER JOIN CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tag t ON t2p.tag_id = t.id GROUP BY t.tag_text
```

When I run the MySQL query directly on the database it works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work. In DQL, the `ON` keyword is replaced by `WITH`.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select('t.tag_text, COUNT(*) as num_tags')
      ->from('CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tag2Post', 't2p')
      ->innerJoin('CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tags', 't', 'WITH', 't2p.tag_id = t.id')
      ->groupBy('t.tag_text')
;
$tags = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Also if you have properly configured entities, you should be able to leave out the `, 'WITH', 't2p.tag_id = t.id'` part as doctrine should automatically find the relations.

For example:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select('t.tag_text, COUNT(*) as num_tags')
      ->from('CompanyWebsiteBundle:Tag2Post', 't2p')
      ->innerJoin('t2p.tags', 't')
      ->groupBy('t.tag_text')
;
$tags = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Many thanks smottt :)  As a side note I'm now getting the following error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 21 near '*) as num_tags': Error: '*' is not defined.`  How would I do `count(*)` in Doctrine2?

Comment: You should define what you want to count. Either t2p.* or t.* or something else.